# "There is … to be" vs. "There is … that has to be"

Tags: grammar, past-participles

Which of these sentences would be the best to write?

1. > There is a house to be built.
2. > There is a house that has to be built.

I wanted to make sure it would be OK to write 'There is+Noun+to be+past participle.'What makes me confused is even though example of the 2nd sentence could be found, I don't see 1st sentence anywhere, e.g. corpus sites, Google. I just want to stick to the proper rules when writing.

Comment: "has yet to be" is completely different from "has to be". **has yet to be** is no stronger than "is yet to be"; whereas **has to be** is an idiomatic phrasal verb denoting "must" or "ought".

Answer (score 1):

*To be built* means someone is planning or intending to build something.

*Has to be built* means someone is required to build something, but there may or may not be plans to build anything yet.